# In GAMS, how to deal with divisions?

Tags: gams-math

In my GAMS model, I have a objective function that involves a division.

GAMS sets the initial values to zero whenever it solves something...*brilliant idea, how could that possibly ever go wrong!*....oh wait, now there's division by zero.

What is the approach to handle this? I have tried manually setting lower bounds such that division by zero is avoided, but then GAMS spits out "infeasible" solution.

Which is wrong, since I know the model is feasible. In fact, removing the division term from my model and resolving does produce a solution. This solution ought to be feasible for the original problem as well, since we are just adding terms to the objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some common approaches:

- set a lower bound. E.g. `Z =E= X/Y`, add `Y.LO = 0.0001;`
- similarly, write something like: `Z =E= X/(Y+0.0001)`
- set a initial value. E.g. `Y.L = 1`
- Multiply both sides by Y: `Z*Y =E= X`

For any non-linear variable you should really think carefully about bounds and initial values (irrespective of division).

Comment: Yeah, I just randomly set some bounds and initial values, and that worked. Thanks. Still feel the approach is slightly clumsy though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the $ sign. For example: A(i,j)$C(i,j) = B(i,j) / C(i,j)